# Correlating between users and connected apps

Tags: rest

Iv'e managed to collect data on both users and connected apps via chatter / metadata API. However - I did not manage to find a way to correlate between the two.

Is it programmatically possible to see which apps are used by a user? or vice versa, for each app get data on who uses it? (Preferably via REST)

Thanks.

Comment: You can see connected app OAuth2 users on the org though can't recall where in the Setup UI - I think it is when you view Connected App details.

Comment: In the UI in the app it is possible, I am trying to do this programatically.

Comment: @PhilW There's a Connected App User's Usage option in the Setup UI, but it doesn't look like there's a way to obtain it programmatically.

Comment: Take a look at the [`OauthToken` metadata type](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_oauthtoken.htm).